# How to select all when i check mark All CheckBox?

Tags: android, list, checkbox

This image shows how my `listview` looks like

[image]

When we check All then all checkboxes should be checked and when unchecked then all checkboxes should be unchecked, here is the `ListView` All is also part of the list view, its position is 0 in map list...

```
public class MultiSelectBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Boolean> selectedList;
    Map<Integer, MultipleSelect> mapList;

    public MultiSelectBaseAdapter(Context context, Map<Integer, MultipleSelect> mapList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mapList = mapList;
        selectedList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0 ; i< mapList.size() ; i++){
            selectedList.add(i, mapList.get(i).isSelected());
        }

        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public List<Boolean> getSelected(){
        return selectedList;
    }

    public Map<Integer, MultipleSelect> getMapList(){
        return mapList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(mapList != null){
            return mapList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mapList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.multiselect_item_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_multiselect);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_multiselect);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.checkBox.setTag(position);

        holder.textView.setText(mapList.get(position).getKeyValueType().getName());

        if(selectedList.get(position)){
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        } else{
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int index = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();
                if(isChecked){
                    selectedList.set(index, true);
                }else{
                    selectedList.set(index, false);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }

}
```

please help me I am new in android, I didn't work with `CheckBox`

[enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 0):

add all selected item ids in your selectedList and then call adapter's **notifyDataSetChanged()** method

Answer (score 0):

Add boolean value to your `MultipleSelect` model and change it when you checked or unchecked and for displaying in `onBindViewHolder` check this value and set checkbox state.

to select all change this value to `true` for each item in map and call:

```
yourMultiselectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

same for deselect all - value to `true` and above call )

Answer (score 0):

i did something like this.
  this is y class side code 
          SelectAll =(Button)findViewById(R.id.footerapproveselectall);
                SelectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String btnlbl = SelectAll.getText().toString();
                    if(btnlbl.equalsIgnoreCase("SelectAll"))
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(Approver.this,AttendanceModelList,1);
                        lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
                        SelectAll.setText("Uncheck All");


                    }else
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        CustomListAdapter adapter=new              CustomListAdapter(Approver.this, AttendanceModelList,2);
                        lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
                        SelectAll.setText("SelectAll");

                    }

                }
            });
```

And this is my adapter side code
         public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

```
private final Activity context;
/*  private final List<String> empname;
    private final List<String> reason;
    private final List<String> empno;
    private final List<String> empdate;
    private final List<String> empDay ;
    private final List<String> empaid;
*/
private Dialog dialog;
private Dialog dialog1;
private Dialog dialogz;
private AlertDialog BackDialog;
int cheki;
Long id;
String Givenregon;


boolean checkAll_flag = false;
boolean checkItem_flag = false;
private final List<AttendanceModel> AttendanceModelList  ;

private TextView NameShow;
private TextView NoShow;
private TextView DayShow;
private TextView DateShow;
private TextView ReasonShow;
private Button Approve;
private Button Cansel;
private Button Reject;
//Date date;
public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, List<AttendanceModel> AttendanceModelList,int cheki)
{
    super(context, R.layout.mylist,AttendanceModelList);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.AttendanceModelList =AttendanceModelList;
    this.cheki =cheki;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView txtTitle;
    protected TextView textemployeedate;
    protected ImageButton View1;
    protected TextView textempday;
    protected  CheckBox Chek1   ;

}

public View getView(int position,View convertview,ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if (convertview == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.idemployeename);
        //TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idreason);
        //TextView txemployee = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idempno);
        viewHolder. textemployeedate = (TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.idempdate);
        viewHolder. textempday = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.idempday);
/*  Button Submit = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btapprove);
 *
 */
    /*Button Cansel = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btreject);*/
        viewHolder. View1 =(ImageButton)convertview.findViewById(R.id.btmylistviewshow);

        viewHolder. Chek1 = (CheckBox)convertview.findViewById(R.id.checkmylist);

        viewHolder.Chek1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                AttendanceModelList.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
            }
        });
        convertview.setTag(viewHolder);
        convertview.setTag(R.id.idemployeename,viewHolder.txtTitle);
        convertview.setTag(R.id.idempday,viewHolder.textempday);
        convertview.setTag(R.id.idempdate,viewHolder.textemployeedate);
        convertview.setTag(R.id.checkmylist,viewHolder.Chek1);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertview.getTag();
    }


    viewHolder.Chek1.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.Chek1.setChecked(AttendanceModelList.get(position).isSelected());
    viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(AttendanceModelList.get(position).getEmpname());






    if(cheki==1)
    {
        viewHolder. Chek1.setChecked(true);
    }
    else if(cheki==2)
    {
        viewHolder. Chek1.setChecked(false);
    }


    return convertview;



};
```

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ListView listView;
    String Name[]={"All","One","Two","Three","Four","Five"};
    boolean Some[]={false,false,false,false,false,false};
    MyAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,Name,Some);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    }

    public void myDAta1(int pos)
    {
         Some[pos]=false;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void myDAta2(int pos)
    {
        Some[pos]=true;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void myDAta3()
    {

        for(int i=0;i<Name.length;i++)
        {
            Some[i]=false;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void myDAta4()
    {

        for(int i=0;i<Name.length;i++)
        {
            Some[i]=true;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


}
```

MyAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String Name[];
    boolean Some[];
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    MyAdapter(Context mContext,String mName[],boolean mSome[])
    {
      this.context=mContext;
      this.Name= mName;
      this.Some=mSome;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Name.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return Name[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final ViewHolder holder ;
        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(Name[position]);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(Some[position]);


        if(position==0) {
            if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
                holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (context instanceof MainActivity) {
                            ((MainActivity) context).myDAta3();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (context instanceof MainActivity) {
                            ((MainActivity) context).myDAta4();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if(holder.checkBox.isChecked())
            {
                holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(context instanceof MainActivity){
                            ((MainActivity)context).myDAta1(position);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(context instanceof MainActivity){
                            ((MainActivity)context).myDAta2(position);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this code

```
@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int index = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();

            if(index==0)
            {
                if (isChecked)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mapList.size(); i++)
                    {
                        MultipleSelect obj = (MultipleSelect) getMapList().get(i);
//                                  obj.setSelected(false);
//                                  arrayList2.set(i, obj);
                        if(obj.isSelected())
                        {
                            selectedList.set(i, false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            selectedList.set(i, true);
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    selectedList.set(index, false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (isChecked)
                {
                    selectedList.set(index, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    selectedList.set(index, false);

                    selectedList.set(0, false);
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
```